# ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

Can someone tell me what that attribute means . How does it works ?

```
NortwhindEntities db=new NorthwindEntities();

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Product product)
{
  db.Product.Add(product);
  Return View();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is used to prevent forgery of requests. Request validation is needed to secure your MVC application.
It works by adding a new 'Anti Forgery Token' hidden field to your form and a cookie; and then validating/comparing the two in a POST request.
Here is an article that explains in more detail [how the anti-forgery mechanism works](http://www.bipinjoshi.net/articles/20e546b4-3ae9-416b-878e-5b12434fe7a6.aspx).